# Split text after the second occurrence of character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I need to split text before the second occurrence of the '-' character.  What I have now is producing inconsistent results.  I've tried various combinations of `rsplit` and read through and tried other solutions on SO, with no results.

Sample file name to split: `'some-sample-filename-to-split'` returned in `data.filename`. In this case, I would only like to have `'some-sample'` returned.

```
fname, extname = os.path.splitext(data.filename)
file_label = fname.rsplit('/',1)[-1]
file_label2 = file_label.rsplit('-',maxsplit=3)
print(file_label2,'\n','---------------','\n')
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> a = "some-sample-filename-to-split"
>>> "-".join(a.split("-", 2)[:2])
'some-sample'
```

`a.split("-", 2)` will split the string upto the second occurrence of `-`.

`a.split("-", 2)[:2]` will give the first 2 elements in the list. Then simply join the first 2 elements.

OR

You could use regular expression : `^([\w]+-[\w]+)`

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = r'^([\w]+-[\w]+)'
>>> re.match(reg, a).group()
'some-sample'
```

**EDIT:** As discussed in the comments, here is what you need:

```
def hyphen_split(a):
    if a.count("-") == 1:
        return a.split("-")[0]
    return "-".join(a.split("-", 2)[:2])

>>> hyphen_split("some-sample-filename-to-split")
'some-sample'
>>> hyphen_split("some-sample")
'some'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If I have some text returned in this format `'ab-c'` and then `'ab-c-d'`. I would like the `'ab'` from the first string and then the `'ab-c'`.  So if there's only one `'-'`, take the preceding text and if there's more than one take the text after the second occurrence.

Comment: @DBS - Well, you can simply use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to count the number of `-` in a string and then simply use an if condition.

Comment: I've been searching for printing characters before the occurrence of the first string and after the occurrence of the second instance of the string (`'-'`) with no luck (constructing an if statement as you suggested).  Do you have any links for a tutorial on this?  Maybe I should post this as another question.

Answer (score 18):

A generic form to split a string into halves on the nth occurence of the separator would be:

```
def split(strng, sep, pos):
    strng = strng.split(sep)
    return sep.join(strng[:pos]), sep.join(strng[pos:])
```

If `pos` is negative it will count the occurrences from the end of string.

```
>>> strng = 'some-sample-filename-to-split'
>>> split(strng, '-', 3)
('some-sample-filename', 'to-split')
>>> split(strng, '-', -4)
('some', 'sample-filename-to-split')
>>> split(strng, '-', 1000)
('some-sample-filename-to-split', '')
>>> split(strng, '-', -1000)
('', 'some-sample-filename-to-split')
```

Comment: Great function. Naming it `half_split()` instead of `split()` eliminates confusion with normal `split()`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str.index()`:

```
def hyphen_split(s):
    pos = s.index('-')
    try:
        return s[:s.index('-', pos + 1)]
    except ValueError:
        return s[:pos]
```

test:

```
>>> hyphen_split("some-sample-filename-to-split")
'some-sample'
>>> hyphen_split("some-sample")
'some'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use regular expressions:

```
import re

file_label = re.search('(.*?-.*?)-', fname).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When proceeding with the dataframe and the split needed
for the entire column values, lambda function is better than regex.

```
df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x.split('-',2)[:2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat cryptic implementation avoiding the use of `join()`:

```py
def split(string, sep, n):
    """Split `string´ at the `n`th occurrence of `sep`"""
    pos = reduce(lambda x, _: string.index(sep, x + 1), range(n + 1), -1)
    return string[:pos], string[pos + len(sep):]
```