# How to substring before nth occurence of a separator?

Tags: java, string, split

```
first;snd;3rd;4th;5th;6th;...
```

How can I split the above after the third occurence of the `;` separator? Especially without having to `value.split(";")` the whole string as an array, as I won't need the values separated. Just the first part of the string up until nth occurence.

Desired output would be:
`first;snd;3rd`.
I just need that as a string substring, not as split separated values.

Comment: Above link is for Python not Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) from Apache

Finds the n-th index within a String, handling null. This method uses String.indexOf(String).

**Parameters:**

> str - the String to check, may be null
>
> searchStr - the String to find, may be null
>
> ordinal - the n-th searchStr to find

Returns:
the n-th index of the search String, -1 (INDEX_NOT_FOUND) if no match or null string input

Or [this way, no libraries required](https://programming.guide/java/nth-occurrence-in-string.html):

```
public static int ordinalIndexOf(String str, String substr, int n) {
    int pos = str.indexOf(substr);
    while (--n > 0 && pos != -1)
        pos = str.indexOf(substr, pos + 1);
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: `ordinalIndexOf()` seems to be just what I was looking for. `value.substring(1, StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(value, ";", 5);` works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with this, easy and basic:

```
String test = "first;snd;3rd;4th;5th;6th;";
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result = test.indexOf(";", result) +1;
}

System.out.println(test.substring(0, result-1));
```

Output:

> first;snd;3rd

You can ofc change the `3` in the loop with the number of arguments you need

Comment: Agreed, keep it simple :)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger obv this can be upgraded with arguments checks etc, but that's not part of the original question , I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regular expressions, it is pretty straightforward:

```
import re
value = "first;snd;3rd;4th;5th;6th;"
reg = r'^([\w]+;[\w]+;[\w]+)'
re.match(reg, value).group()
```

Outputs:

```
"first;snd;3rd"
```

More options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300158/python-split-text-after-the-second-occurrence-of-character) .

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex that uses a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match from the start of the string not a semicolon.

Then repeat a grouping structure 2 times that matches a semicolon followed by not a semicolon 1+ times.

```
^[^;]+(?:;[^;]+){2}
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `[^;]+` Negated character class to match not a semicolon 1+ times
- `(?:` Start non capturing group
- `;[^;]+` Match a semicolon and 1+ times not a semi colon
- `){2}` Close non capturing group and repeat 2 times

For example:

```
String regex = "^[^;]+(?:;[^;]+){2}";
String string = "first;snd;3rd;4th;5th;6th;...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // first;snd;3rd
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Oq7gQZ)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use split, just use indexOf in a for loop to know the index of the 3rd and 4th ";" then do a substring between these index.

Also you can do a split with a regex that match the 3rd ; but it's probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this frequently it is best to compile the regex upfront in a static Pattern instance:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NthOccurance {

    static Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("^(([^;]*;){3}).*");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String in="first;snd;3rd;4th;5th;6th;";
        Matcher m=pattern.matcher(in);
        if (m.matches())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Replace the '3' by the number of elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below code find index of 3rd occurence of ';' character and make substring.

```
String s = "first;snd;3rd;4th;5th;6th;";
String splitted = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(";", s.indexOf(";", s.indexOf(";") + 1) + 1));
```