# Polars - Split string after the n occurrence of the character

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to split a string after the second occurrence of the `_` character, following an approach similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300158/split-text-after-the-second-occurrence-of-character).
I want to use a polars expression, as I have a column containing strings separated by multiple `_`.
My current approach is based on using `pl.col("mycol").str.split("_")`, then removing elements from the list output that are not needed. However, this is not an efficient approach.

Do you have any suggestion on how to improve/simplify this process?

This is an example of the process I am currently following

```
pl.select(
    pl.lit("my_string_occurrence").str.split("_")
    ).select(
        pl.col("literal").list.slice(0,2).list.join("_")
        )
```

Which gives me as output:

```
┌───────────┐
│ literal   │
│ ---       │
│ str       │
╞═══════════╡
│ my_string │
└───────────┘
```

Comment: You want to remove everything after (and including) the second `_`? e.g. `.str.replace(r"(^[^_]*_[^_]*)_.*", "$1")`?

Comment: @jqurious Probably want `.str.extract(r"(^[^_]*_[^_]*)_.*")` instead of replace

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Indeed, both of them allow me to extract the desired output -@jqurious approach may be better, as it allows me to avoid null values produced by str.extract()-. Hopefully, in the future the str.split() expression will allow to input similar parameters as the Pandas version.

Comment: @yz_jc What parameters do you need? `n`? `expand`? There is also a [`.splitn()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.splitn.html#polars.Expr.str.splitn) but that still requires some post-processing.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Ah, thanks - forgot about `.extract()` - I suppose we can simplify the pattern in that case: `.str.extract(r"(^[^_]*_[^_]*)")`

Answer (score 1):

```py
pl.select( 
    pl.lit("my_string_occurrence").str.splitn("_",2)
    .struct.rename_fields(["not_searching", "found"])
    .struct.field("found")
)
```